# How to fix jump when click on search bar?

Tags: ios, uikit, uisearchcontroller

There is a phenomenon that jumps when you click the search bar.

The view is below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFkgS.gif

---

my code.

```swift
lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    return searchController
}()

func setUpNavigationItem() {
    navigationItem.title = "Search"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true

    let loginButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Login", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    loginButton.tintColor = .label
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = loginButton
}
```

Do you know how to solve it?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621515-edgesforextendedlayout

I have set "under top bars" of "extend edge" options in ViewController to "false".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRO1W.png

It was solved this way!